# Eclipse RCP Application dependencies order

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, eclipse-rcp, jogl

**Info:**
I have a question before i start my project. I want to create a eclipse rcp application that uses jogl. There is a great tutorial on doing that:

[Wadewalkers Tutorial](https://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/tutorial-a-cross-platform-workbench-program-using-java-opengl-and-eclipse/)

**Problem:**
I need to include 2 libraries that i wrote on my own. One is no problem because it has no dependencies. The other one depends on some jogl libraries to build it. The final application uses the jogl libraries too. How can i include the necessary libraries in the right order, that there are no conflicts between the jogl libs and my 2 libs?

**Thoughts:**
Include the jogl lib during development for my own lib. Create the actual app and include my lib and the jogl libs again?

Comment: Why not using Maven in order to avoid having to bundle the binaries in your project?

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Im using now maven and it takes care of all dependencies. Great tool!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Migrating to Maven isn't always possible but when it is, it allows to benefit of an easier dependency management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you refer to already describes how you create a plugin with platform dependent fragments from the JOGL libraries. Thus, the 'cleanest' way would be to create a [plugin project](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Ftutorial%2FpdeProject.html) for each of your libraries.

In the manifest of your library (now plugin) that depends on the JOGL library you [define a dependency](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm) to the JOGL plugin. And as described in the tutorial you add your plugins as dependencies to the RCP application as it is done for the JOGL plugin. If you do this in this way you can work in parallel on all projects if they are in the same Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As i started the project it was clearer to me how the dependencies work together. With maven its a lot easier too. I think i will always use maven for this kind of projects now. :)